# Issues installing Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, ibm

I am very new to Linux and am trying to install Ubuntu Server onto a IBM AC1-7978 Server. I boot from CD and get threw all the setup until it tries to partition and make the file system. When it gets to that point it says failed to create ex3 file system. I've exhausted every idea I've had. The only thing I can think of is im using a RAID array and in the settings write cache is disabled and it won't let me enable it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
It uses ServeRAID-8k-l SAS

Comment: did you tell the installer that it is a RAID array when setting up partitions?

Comment: Yes I did, and I tried not setting up an array but then none of my drives are recognized

Comment: Also when setting up the array for whatever reason it won't let me change the RAID type, it defaults to volume and doesn't let me change it

Comment: Can you try installing it with an ordinary non-RAID disk, or with the RAID configured as JBOD? If that works, you can see whether additional drivers need to be installed to support your RAID.

Comment: I updated it, it's a ServeRAID-8k-l SAS

Comment: Mark, if I set it up without the RAID configured it doesn't recognize the disk is there